# How to do Hierarchical Clustering for Ordinal data-set in R?

Tags: r, ordinal, hclust, record-linkage

I am trying to do Hierarchical clustering on a dataset where the columns are ordinal on the scale of 1 to 5.

Based on Hierarchical clustering can be done using `hclust()` function.

1. For doing analysis with ordinal data, we should use "Max" distance or Chebyshev distance method.
2. But which Linkage should I use with Chebyshev distance as most of the Linkage using squared Euclidean distance. like following linkage methods - Ward, Centroid and Median use squared Euclidean distance.

Linkage - ward.D, ward.D2, Single, Complete, Average, Centroid, median.

So what Linkage should I use with Chebyshev distance to do hierarchical clustering for Ordinal Data?

Comment: This is not a programming question, you should send your question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: clustering is very arbitrary, therefore you should try a couple of different combinations of distance metrics and clustering algorithms and 1) see what works for you and 2) if they give consistent results.

Comment: @gdkrmr Is it fine to do hierarchical clustering with Ward.D2 linkage with max distance of data, as it is mentioned ward.D2 always takes squared euclidean distance as measure?

Comment: you provide a `dist` object to `hclust()`, if I read the documentation right, the elements of `dist` are squared when using `"ward.D2"`. So from a technical point of view it does not matter where the `dist` object comes from, from a theoretical point of view I don't know enough about the Ward method to give you a definitive answer. General experience tells me that you should try out many combinations and settle on the one you like.